# Ssh port forwarding google compute engine

Tags: linux, ssh, google-compute-engine

I am trying to forward traffic with google instances but no luck.
Here is the scenario:
I have 2 instances currently main-server, and mini-server-1
I want to ssh mini-server-1 from main-server and create a dynamic port forwarding like so:

> gcloud compute ssh "mini-server-1" --zone="us-central1-f" --ssh-flag="-D:5551" --ssh-flag="-N" --ssh-flag="-n" &

I have this error:

> bind: Cannot assign requested address

I tried: `ssh -N username@mini-server-1(all ips internal external, hostname) -D 5551 &`

When i run netstat i can see that ports are free.
Here is wget with proxy from main-server

> wget google.com -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=127.0.0.1:5551
>
> Connecting to 127.0.0.1:5551... connected.
>   Proxy request sent, awaiting response...

Does someone know how can i achieve this?

Comment: PS. Alos i modified sshd_config and added AllowTcpForwarding yes, but still the same results

Comment: if you use http_proxy will not connect, test with https_proxy in the wget command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run the command with the debug flag to help you find more information:

```
gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag=-vvv "mini-server-1" \
                   --zone="us-central1-f" \
                   --ssh-flag="-D:5551" \
                   --ssh-flag="-N" \
                   --ssh-flag="-n" &
```

and as mention in my comment before, use https_proxy.

Comment: Yes, this works, apparently it was binding to ipv6 so i added --ssh-flag="-4". And also using standard ssh like ssh  -N -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=100000, just add --ssh-flag="ServerAliveCountMax=100000" ?

Answer (score 33):

Much simpler syntax:

```
gcloud compute ssh my-vm-name --zone=europe-west1-b -- -NL 4000:localhost:4000
```

You can pass as many options as you want:

```
-NL 8080:localhost:80 -NL 8443:localhost:443
```

- https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely
- https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce
- https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-port-forwarding-set-up-load-testing-on-compute-engine

Comment: Wow I had no idea one could forward many ports at once :- )  Thanks.  B.t.w. `-NL 127.0.0.1:8080: ....` is a little bit more secure? (access to the tunnel from localhost only)

Answer (score 7):

```
gcloud compute  ssh --ssh-flag="-L 2222:localhost:8080"  --zone "us-central1-a" "your_instance_name"
```

> With this command you can port forward and connect to a port running on a particular VM instance from your local PC 
> 2222 refer to local IP 
> 8080 is the remote port where our application will be running

Comment: couldn't make it work. Somewhere it says Ubuntu users should -ML instead of -L